# WPF Adding a datatrigger to the ImageSource of a user control from another control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatrigger

I have the following usercontrol:

```
<Border
        Style="{StaticResource notificationBarBorderStyle}"
        Height="21"
        >
        <StackPanel
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            Style="{StaticResource notificationBarStyle}"
            >
            <DockPanel>
                <Image
                    Width="17"
                    Height="16"
                    Margin="4,0,11,0"
                    Source="{Binding ElementName=NotificationControl, Path=ImageSource}"
                    />
                <TextBlock
                    x:Name="notificationTextBlock"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"
                    Text="{Binding ElementName=NotificationControl, Path=Message}"
                    />
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

and then in another usercontrol i try to reference it like so:

```
<Controls:NotificationBarControl
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="0"
                DataContext="{Binding IncomingResult}"
                Message="{Binding TaskResultsMessage}"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowTaskResults, Converter={StaticResource boolToHiddenVisibilityConverter}}"
                Command="{Binding DisplayTaskError}"
                ImageSource="{DynamicResource somePicture1}"
                >
```

I want to be able to put a data trigger on the image source so that depending on the state of a boolean flag, a different image will appear (call it somePicture2). I do not really want to do much to change the control itself, as it is referenced a few times in a rather large project and I do not want to break anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `Style` property of the control to a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to your `bool` property:

```
<Controls:NotificationBarControl
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="0"
                DataContext="{Binding IncomingResult}"
                Message="{Binding TaskResultsMessage}"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowTaskResults, Converter={StaticResource boolToHiddenVisibilityConverter}}"
                Command="{Binding DisplayTaskError}">
    <Controls:NotificationBarControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Controls:NotificationBarControl">
            <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{StaticResource somePicture1}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourBooleanSourceProperty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{StaticResource somePicture2}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Controls:NotificationBarControl.Style>
</Controls:NotificationBarControl>
```